# How to stop docker-compose from writing to syslog?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rsyslog

In my syslog file up to 20% of all entries are generated by docker-compose and I don't know why.

The logging driver of all containers is json-file, so why are these logs even appearing in the syslog file?

Souldn't the logs only be written to /var/lib/docker/containers/{id}/{id}-json.log ?

Does somebody have an idea what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define "none" as driver.

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

[Dokumentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

Comment: Yes that would be a possible solution. But originally I wanted logging to be active and I just don't understand why the driver json-file is writing to syslog.

Comment: Maybe take a look here think that could solve your problem. [Link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-default-logging-driver)